# Adding a SharePoint list to an Update Panel

Tags: 2010, development, list-view-web-part, updatepanel

I am trying to add a SharePoint list to an AJAX Update Panel. I am doing this by adding a ListViewWebPart to the Update Panel. My code:

```
SPList fcsRequestList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Requests List");

ListViewWebPart lvWP = new ListViewWebPart();
lvWP.ZoneID = "Header";
lvWP.ListName = fcsRequestList.ID.ToString().ToUpper();
lvWP.ViewGuid = fcsRequestList.DefaultView.ID.ToString().ToUpper();

UpdatePanelRequestList.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lvWP);
```

When I do this I get the error `"< !-- #RENDER FAILED -- >"`

I have tried using different views with no luck. Is there a way to solve this error or a better way to display a list in an Update Panel?

I am using SharePoint 2010. This is a Visual Web Part project that contains an Update Panel inside it, which then contains the code above.

Comment: I think technically a WebPart has to live directly within a WebPartZone, but I may be wrong about this.

Comment: If so, can I add an Update Panel to the web part zone and add the list inside that panel?

Comment: I don't believe you can have any intermediary containers. I believe it has to live directly within the WebPartZone.

Comment: I clarified in my post that this is a Visual Web Part project that I am adding to the Header zone of a Web Part page. So this is an Update Panel, inside a Visual Web Part that is placed in a Web Part zone.